# Which jQuery plugin should I use for a "placeholder"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, placeholder

On the web, most of site have search box. Some of these search box have a **search...** placeholder text which when cursor set in search box this text was appear. Is this done with jQuery? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

This may be HTML5 feature called placeholder. It does not require JavaScript ([see proof](http://jsfiddle.net/TnRvb/)). It works like that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search" />
```

Alternatively you can just use some extension listed eg. [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

No need for a plugin to do this.

You must bind the .focus() and .blur() states of the input box

on focus() you clear the textbox, on blur() if nothing enter return the default value

Check this Demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/QvPCX/

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search.." />
```

JS

```
jQuery('input[name="search"]').focus(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "Search..") {
            jQuery(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "") {
            jQuery(this).val('Search..');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new `placeholder` attribute in HTML5 which takes care of this natively. If you cannot use HTML5 for whatever reason, there is a jquery fallback available here: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: How can i use HTML 5 most of tag work in old browser? thz for your comment.

Comment: To use HTML5 you just need to change the doctype of your page. Note, however, that this may cause errors in older browsers unless you use a HTML5shiv, or a derivative. If you need to support old browsers I'd suggest using the jquery method in the link I posted.